# org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to read class name from file

Tags: ignite

I have a 3 node Apache Ignite Cluster, I have created a cache with Integer as Key and a 'Subscriber' POJO as value, when I connect to the cluster from inside a JAVA program and access the cache , I get the above mentioned exception, I have 'peerclassloading' property set to false, and I have deployed 'Subscriber'  POJO Binaries in all the nodes, Please find the complete stack trace below. What am I missing here? Why is it looking for some file inside my IGNITE_HOME when I am starting client inside my JAVA program with `Ignition.start()`?

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to read class name from file [id=-1219769240, file=/home/benakaraj/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/work/marshaller/-1219769240.classname]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.className(MarshallerContextImpl.java:158)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:483)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1443)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:537)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:117)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectContext.java:280)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:145)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:132)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1748)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.setResult(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:598)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.onResult(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:454)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.processNearSingleGetResponse(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:153)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$1200(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:128)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$11.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:295)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$11.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:293)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:582)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:280)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:204)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$000(GridCacheIoManager.java:80)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:163)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:821)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1600(GridIoManager.java:103)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:784)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/benakaraj/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/work/marshaller/-1219769240.classname (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.className(MarshallerContextImpl.java:154)
... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the cache tries to deserialize the value after retrieving it from cache, but you don't have a class for it on the node where `IgniteCache.get()` was called. You can either deploy the class, or use `IgniteCache.withKeepBinary()` to avoid deserialization: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#binaryobject-cache-api

Comment: I am also facing same issue. In my case, I want to keep cache classes in different package namings for server/client apps. Is there any config to acheive this?

Comment: @San Not sure I understand, can you please elaborate on what you want to achieve? Generally speaking, classes located in different packages are different independent classes, even if their simple names are the same. There is no specific support for such a case, and I don't think it even makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be pretty simple, Ignite looks for the user defined POJOs from the list of classes loaded by default class loader, if it does not find it there , it looks inside marshalled classes, In my case, my value POJO was inside the test resources , hence default class loader was not loading the class, causing ignite to look inside marshalled classes folder(IGNITE_HOME/work/marshaller/) .